# How to find uninitialized variables in C on Linux?

Tags: linux, c

My C source code has many unintialized variables. The code is on RHEL 6.4 operating system.

Is there a way to find all the uninitialized variables?

Comment: Are you looking for a C debugger for Linux?

Comment: No, I am not looking for a debugger. I just want to find all the un-initialized variables in my source code.

Comment: this question lacks a proper definition of "uninitialized variable"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finding *all* of them is impossible, in the mathematical sense (at least without false-positives). However, there are some tools to help find some of them:

- Turn on compiler warnings. With `gcc`, this would be `-Wuninitialized`, `-Winit-self`, and `-Wmaybe-uninitialized`. Note that you will need to try this with various levels of optimization; you'll get different warnings at different `-O` levels. Note that `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` (as the name suggests) may give false positives.
- For uninitialized memory (as in `malloc`, etc.), you can use `valgrind`. This actually requires running the program.
- Static checkers such as [splint](http://www.splint.org/). (Thanks to [Andy Lester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester) for this suggestion.)

Comment: Valgrind does pretty poorly at recognizing use of uninitialized **variables**. In fact, I do't know if it tried to detect them at all. It does great for detecting use of uninitialized **malloc()-allocated blocks**. In its defense, use of uninitialized variables is hard to detect at the binary level.

Comment: @PascalCuoq indeed, you'll notice I specified "for uninitialized memory". That's a related problem (and one I wouldn't be surprised to find in a codebase with uninitialized variable problems), so I figured I'd mention it. I'll clarify.

Comment: Why is find all them impossible? Didn't compiler knows when a variable was used in an assignment?

Comment: @TheMask A `int a; if (someFunc()) { a = 1 }; a*= 2` ... was `a` used uninitialized? It's impossible in the general case to decide if [the function even returns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) much less if it returns true or false.

Comment: I got now. I totally missed this... I was thinking that a variable is initialized just by the fact = operator was used in. My definition of `uninitialized variable` was totally wrong.

Comment: @derobert You spelled the tool `split` instead of `splint` like the URL; and SO says I can't make a 1 character edit.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're using GCC, compile your program with -Wuninitialized.  Better to just always compile with -Wall, because with C a programmer needs all the help he can get.

Comment: If you're going to use `-Wall`, you should use `-Wextra` as well. I've also heard people say that you can get different warnings if you use `-g` and/or `-O`.

Comment: Indeed, I do, but it takes getting used to.  Some of the warnings it produces seem pointless until you reach the necessary state of paranoia.

Comment: "necessary state of paranoia" - I like that

Comment: Also, I guess it takes a special kind of paranoia to use **-Wall -Wextra -Werror** by default, as I do :/

Comment: GCC does not detect that `x` is used uninitialized in the program `int *p;

int main(int c, char **v)
{
  int x;
  p = &x;
  return x;
}
`

Comment: Throw clang at it, too.